# Electromagnetic waves & observer effect

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, observers

So I’ve been doing some research & realised that they done the double slit experiment with large molecules and the molecule behaved as a wave , so does this mean that all matter is really just a wave that becomes concentrated energy when observed ? Is the mind what is holding the physical world together ? If we are not looking is the universe just an ocean of information ? If we are waves then waves of what kind ? Everything in the universe is electromagnetic so does this not imply that we are made of electromagnetic waves capable of moving at light speed ? Brain waves are definitely electromagnetic so what does this entail ? Is our consciousness/mind made of light ? This would explain how people have transcended space/time through meditation . Just a few questions I’d like to hear the answers too .

Comment: *Everything in the universe is electromagnetic...* Not at all

Comment: Could you explain what is not electromagnetic ? What about the electromagnetic force ? Does that not say that even on the atomic level that electromagnetism is at work ?

Comment: I get the point you are trying to make. The thing is with all the matter are associated matter waves. And world behaves very differently in quantum and classical level. In quantum level, you can see how a particle behaves as a wave and a particle but that is very very difficult to observe in classical mechanics. If we were quantum particles, your question would might have a positive answer.